# Problem installing rmagick gem on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rmagick

I'm trying to push a Rails app to Heroku, but it's failing when it tries to build the rmagick gem (which is specified in the Gemfile). I've done `bundle install` locally and the app runs fine.

But, on Heroku in the pre-receive hook, after it build the rmagick examples, I get:

```
make install

/usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/ruby setup.rb install
rm -f InstalledFiles
---> lib
mkdir -p /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib
install RMagick.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/
---> lib/rvg
mkdir -p /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install embellishable.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install pathdata.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install stylable.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install describable.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install deep_equal.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install misc.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install text.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install rvg.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install container.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install stretchable.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install paint.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install clippath.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install units.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
install transformable.rb /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/rvg
<--- lib/rvg
<--- lib
---> ext
---> ext/RMagick
mkdir -p /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib
install RMagick.so /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/lib/.
<--- ext/RMagick
<--- ext
post-install.rb: installing documentation...
mkdir /usr/ruby1.8.7/share/RMagick
hook /disk1/tmp/build_3eu8mw7r34j0f/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.17/./post-install.rb failed:
Permission denied - /usr/ruby1.8.7/share/RMagick
Try 'ruby setup.rb --help' for detailed usage.
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Then it bails out of the push. I'm using the bamboo-ree-1.8.7 stack. Do I need to add something extra to get it to work? Alternatively, it seems that it's only a documentation problem. I don't need the documentation on Heroku, so can I disable that instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You Gemfile entry should be:

```
gem "rmagick", :require => 'RMagick'
```

Comment: Thanks. I have it like that currently, and I also tried it with `gem "rmagick", "~> 1.15.17", :require => 'RMagick'` (this was the version recommended by the app). Both variants try to install 1.15.17 and fail as above.

Comment: Ah, yep, seems that that older version of rmagick just wasn't compatible with that Heroku stack. Using a newer version worked. Thanks.