# How to manipulate PNG images using ImageMagick on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm using rmagick gem, and I had to install [the PNG library from here](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/) locally.

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-1 Q16 x86_64 2014-05-12 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules
Delegates: bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png xml zlib
```

But on Heroku, I don't have this delegate:

```
~ $ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

And it's impossible to install it, because Heroku don't let me use `sudo`.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**Update 17/11:**

I already using the `rmagick` gem in my app. But, I have to manipulate PNG images and ImageMagick requires the png delegate to do this.

My problem isn't the gem. But the png delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Heroku buildpack to install the dependencies.

There's an [ImageMagick buildpack available here](https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick-cedar-14). Just follow the instructions will do. 
Feel free to search "ImageMagick buildpack" on the web if you're not using Cedar14 stack.

Update on Nov 17:

Interesting, seems like Heroku already has ImageMagick installed(which explains why I don't have this problem when I use Paperclip gem) and it's pretty easy to require Rmagick class as show in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717268/problem-installing-rmagick-gem-on-heroku). Explained in [here too](http://support.run.pivotal.io/entries/46260333-Unable-to-get-rmagick-to-work-with-pushed-app).

```
gem "rmagick", :require => 'RMagick'
```

Comment: Thanks @nayiaw, but I don't know how to run it. I added the buildpack to heroku using `heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi` and created the `.buildpacks` file. So what now? It's a little confusing

Comment: Commit your buildpacks and deploy to Heroku. The deploy hook will go through the buildpack and install it.

Comment: I've created [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757295/install-imagemagick-on-heroku)

Comment: I've updated my answer here, it's more related to this question than other.

Comment: @nayivan, you are right! We just need to declare `rmagick` gem. My issue was other.